# I am trying to create a table running flyway migration on Maria db and want to save images blob in the table?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mariadb, migration, flyway

Any idea how i can save it without writing a big sql files. The images are less than the size of MEDIUMBLOB . But writing sql to create and insert data into table is very clumsy and not maintainable.

Current implementation:
I am using spring boot with flyway migration on mariadb

```
resources
   db.migration
      - V2__init.sql
      - V3__insert_table_data.sql
```

Inside V2__init.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
(
    id PRIMARY KEY,
    image MEDIUMBLOB
);
```

Inside V3__insert_table_data.sql

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (‘some_id’,’<very_big_image_data>’)
```

How i can read the image file directly into sql and insert the entry in the table.
Any help and idea is appreciated :)

Comment: Are the files stored on the server machine?

Comment: No from local stored in the repository itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was something similar that our team encountered and tried a couple of attempts to use sql-based flyway migration initially

Due to the complexity of storing the blob with using SQL statements, we moved to use spring JDBC templates in a java-based migration script. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#java-based-migrations

In regards to your question, we would need to create a separate folder called db.migration within your src/main/java folder in order for flyway to pick up the java based migration and run it sequentially according to the version numbers provided in the name.

```
src
   main
      java
        com.example.package
        db.migration
          - V3__insert_table_data.java
      resources
        db.migration
          - V2__init.sql
```

Sample implementation for using spring jdbc templates and reading of image files from machine. This assumes images are checked in together with source code

```
public class V3__insert_table_data extends BaseJavaMigration {
    public void migrate(Context context) {
      var image = getImageFromFile("filename.svg");
      var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('id1', '" + image + "')";

      new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(context.getConnection(), true))
                .execute(insertStatement);
    }
}

//helper method to retrieve images from file system
private String getImageFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
   try(FileInputStream image = new FileInputStream("pathToImage/" + fileName)){
    var bytes = logo.readAllBytes();
     
    // You might want to Base64 encode the image to prevent any sql grammar insertion error happening
    var encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
    return new String(encodedBytes);
  }
}
```